# How to assign events in revealing prototype pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to implement Revealing Module Pattern. I need to assign an event handler to one of elements, this event handler is a function I define in protoype but I get **this.trigger is not a function** error.

Here's what I have done:

```
//constructor
var MyClass = function (settings) {
   this.someElement=$(settings.elementID);
}

//prototype    
MyClass.prototype = function() {
    var init = function() {
        this.someElement.change(this.handler);
    },
        handler = function() {
        this.someElement.hide();
    };

    return {
        init : init,
        handler : handler
    };
}();
```

Here's how I call it:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.init();
```

Comment: I don't see where the `this.trigger` is comming from.

Comment: I am trying to do something with this.someElement in handler. Is that a problem with closure?

Comment: one issue I see is that within MyClass.prototype, handler is not being scoped correctly.  without "var" it is being declared globally, which you probably don't want.  Probably not the issue, but you should fix it nonetheless.  So are you trying to call handler from a "new" instance?  You should also post the code that is calling this method.

Comment: @thescientist It has a var clause from the previous declaration. Notice the ','

Comment: I don't understand some people's insistenance on `var a,<cr> b,<cr> c` when spread over separate lines - I much prefer `var a; <cr>var b;` and find it far less error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your constructor should be

```
var MyClass = function (settings) {
    this.someElement = jQuery("#" + settings.elementID);
}
```

Then you will be able to call jQuerys `trigger` method on that element with `(new MyClass({elementID:"someid"})).someElement.trigger()`, because "trigger" is a method of the jQuery instance which is the "someElement" property of your object.

Also, your handler won't work because it is called in context of the element, not of your object. So it should be

```
MyClass.prototype.init = function init() {
    this.someElement.change(this.handler || function defaulthandler() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
};
```